# Href #! JQuery syntax error

Tags: jquery

I´m using Simrou javascript routing system

```
<a href="#!add"></a>
```

Using Simrou

```
var editRoute = router.addRoute('!:id');
editRoute.get(function(event, params) {
$this = params.id;
window[$this](); });
```

Which calls the "add" JS function correctly. So i end up having this url to call "add" function:

```
http://wwww.test.com/#!add
```

But JQuery throws this error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!add
```

If i remove the "!" it works without errors, but the idea is to have the "!" following Google Ajax crawling. How can i fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont have any JQuery inside the "add" function, but some JQuery libraries are loaded, do you think the problem is related with one? But without "!" everything works great.

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html it answers your question.

Comment: Also, any symbol following "#" will throw a error. Ex: "/", "&", etc.

Comment: Hi. I´m still confused, based on the Google Ajax Crawling guide i need to add the exclamation mark to href, but adding the "!" will cause a Jquery error..what i´m missing?